# Regex to catch everything after last '/' in URL

Tags: ios, swift, regex, url

```
let url1 = "https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/files/2020/01/exmaple1.jpg"
let url2 = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/7/b/9/11974343961963318467fl.png"
let url3 = "https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/01+Seth+Easy+v1.gif"
```

How can I catch everything after last slash, so in this cases:
`exmaple1.jpg` 
`11974343961963318467fl.png` 
`01+Seth+Easy+v1.gif`

Comment: For URL, you can use `yourUrl.lastPathComponent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`components(separatedBy:)`** and get the **`last`** component from it, i.e.

```
url1.components(separatedBy: "/").last //"exmaple1.jpg"
url2.components(separatedBy: "/").last //"11974343961963318467fl.png"
url3.components(separatedBy: "/").last //"01+Seth+Easy+v1.gif"
```

Or you can use **`lastPathComponent`** on the `URL` instance created using `url1, url2 and url3`

```
URL(string: url1)?.lastPathComponent //"exmaple1.jpg"
URL(string: url2)?.lastPathComponent //"11974343961963318467fl.png"
URL(string: url3)?.lastPathComponent //"01+Seth+Easy+v1.gif"
```